# I want to encrypt newgroupkey using publickey and they decrypt it. How to do that?

Tags: security, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key

**Below code is public key and secretkey generation. I want to encrypt secretkey using public keya nd decrypt vise versa.**

```
publickey=intent.getStringExtra("Public key");
KeyGenerator keyGenerator2 = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
            KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
            keyGenerator2.init(128);
            SecretKey newgroupKey = keyGenerator2.generateKey();
            byte[] groupkeydata = newgroupKey.getEncoded();
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking -- any data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the secret key.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: The terminology is public/private keys for asymmetric cryptography and secret key for symmetric cryptography.